# UIButton simple subclass (need to have an NSString property like a tag)

Tags: iphone, uibutton, subclass

I have a view that has a bunch of programmatically-created UIButton objects (rounded rectangle type), but I need to store a little bit of information in them, identifying each button. I was doing fine with the tag, but the numbers got too large, and I would like to basically have another piece of info associated with each button, this time an NSString. By the way, the label is taken, I can't use that. What's the simplest/quickest way to go about this? Do I need to subclass UIButton and add my own property to it like stringTag? I'm not super proficient in obj-c yet, and read somewhere this is a pain. Is there a simpler way to store an additional string in my UIButtons? Thanks a lot in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclassing uibutton is a real pain. They don't usually work as expected since UIButton is an abstract class. Therefore to make a fully working button you may have to override quite a few methods to get the button to do everything the the Apple subclasses do. Instead if you just need to add storage you can use [associative references](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html). you must `#import <objc/runtime.h>` to use the functions.

The best way to do this is to define a string constant `NSString *const buttonTagName = @"com.youapp.buttonTag";` and store tags with this as the key `objc_setAssociatedObject(button, buttonTagName, tagForCurrentButton, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);` .

Comment: Interesting, thanks, did not know this was possible. Looks like it might be the simplest way to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding an `NSString` with some id info shouldn't mess up your `UIButton` subclass too much. At least it's easy to try it out, we are talking 10 lines of code here. I subclassed a UIButton and overrided initWithFrame method once and got it working correctly. But it's true, it is a pain and don't ask me why I did it :)

Comment: Yea, I've just never subclassed a uibutton before and I've read in a bunch of places it's tough to do. I might end up doing this anyway so I can draw custom-looking buttons. Thanks for your answer